# How to make custom regular Expression

Tags: regex

I want to make a regular expression which can match text in Following way:

Search Text: How

Result:

> T`h`is is `how` we learn Regular Expressi`o`n. `How`ever we can n`o`t learn everyt`h`ing.

Currently I am using this Regular Expression:

My Regular Expression : `/([how])\w/g` But I am not getting the desired result. What I am missing?

Comment: you mean, `[how]+`?..

Comment: is their need of /g?

Comment: @nicael `[how]` does not matches `However`

Comment: ...so..you want to search for the "how" word only? just put .. "/how|How/"

Comment: @nicael sorry it was a typo mistake I updated mu question

Comment: And `o` in Expression?

Comment: so you want to match all the "h"s "o"s and "w"s as well?

Comment: @KiraCrafter No.. I am getting it from user I can be anything. `How` is just an example

Comment: @TiborB. yes you are right

Comment: You might need the case insensitivity flag.

Comment: /how/ if you want to find the word 'how' /[how]/ finds the letters 'h' 'o' and 'w'

Comment: Remove the square brackets from your regex

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. "How" is not matched, only "how". You should use the `i` modifier for case insensitivity.

Comment: thanx @nicael it is working

Comment: square brackets are perfectly fine, as he's defining a custom character class.

Comment: use [howHOW] or i modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so you want to match all the "h"s "o"s and "w"s as well

Based on your feedback in comments, after getting a user-defined search word, you want to search for every character there is in the word. For your case with `How`, it is not a big problem, just enclose it with `[` and `]` to form a character class, apply a `+` quantifier to it (one or more occurrences) and use a `/i` case insensitive modifier to make the pattern and search itself case insensitive.

```
/[How]+/ig
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kG3zE9/1)

However, it is advisable to escape `^`, `[`, `]`, `-` and `\` characters inside the character class. So, do not forget to add that escaping step to your final code.

Comment: thanks for your help..Will u also help me assist to escape `space` . currently I am removing `space` from my search string via some coding..but I want to escape every `space` character and search only words. is it possible? or I have to remove `space` via coding and then make regexp

Comment: Could you explain with a sample string, keyword and expected output?

Comment: Suppose user enters string `How is` to search in string `How to post a question in SO` then I want to list all `How`s , `H`s , `o`s , `h`s , `w`s , `i` , `s`s considering it is a case-insensitive compare.. But not the space between the `how` and `is`.

Comment: I think you can remove the space and process the pattern as in the question: [`/[Howis]+/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/tR5eY0/1) Or do you want to avoid matching `i`s and `s`s in the words containing `h`s, `o`s and `w`s?